# How many people must be in a room until it is at least a $50\%$ chance that two will have the same amount of change?

Tags: probability, solution-verification, self-learning, birthday

**Book problem:** If the amount of change in a pocket is assumed to be uniformly distributed from $0$ to $99$ cents, how many people must be in a room until it is at least a $50\%$ chance that two will have the same amount of change?

**Book answer:** $P(10)\{\text{no duplicate}\} = 0.5031$

**My solution:** I interpret the question as asking for the chance that 'at least' two people will have the same amount of change.

I flip the problem to find when no one will have the same amount of change. If there were $k$ people in the room, $k < 100$, then the number of ways that they would each have different amounts is the same as the number of permutations of $k$ from the 100 options, so $\frac{100!}{(100-k)!}$.

The number of total scenarios for the $k$ people is $100^k$.

Hence the probability of no duplicates in the room is the quotient

$$
\frac{100!}{100^k(100-k)!}.
$$

So for at least two people to have the same amount of change in their pockets, the opposite of no duplicates, would be

$$
1 - \frac{100!}{100^k(100-k)!}
$$

and we want this to be at least $1/2$.

**Question:** Is this not $k = 13$ which seems to contradict the book answer of $10$?

**Book:** "Methods of Mathematics" by Hamming

Comment: This looks like a version of the birthday problem.  I think $P_{10}\{\text{no duplicate}\} \approx 0.6282$,  $P_{11}\{\text{no duplicate}\} \approx 0.5653$,  $P_{12}\{\text{no duplicate}\} \approx 0.50315$ and  $P_{13}\{\text{no duplicate}\} \approx 0.4428$ so I would agree with you on $13$

Comment: Why did you interpret the question as asking for the probability of *at least* two people having the same amount of change? The question only mentions two people, and that usually means **exactly** two

Comment: @H.sapiensrex - that would, if anything, push the required number up further

Comment: @H.sapiensrex  I don't understand. If you stop the trial the moment at least two people share a birthday, then, at that moment, exactly two people will share a birthday.  Or are you thinking of something else?

Comment: @H.sapiensrex That was my first reading of the problem too.  But my solution in that case gave a much smaller number of people than $10$ so I assumed I was misreading it.  Would you like me to show my work?

Comment: @Henry I think so too.  The birthday problem was a worked-through example in the book just preceding the exercise set where this problem appeared.  So my interpretation and work looks sound to you?

Comment: I think this is just a typo in the book, and $P_{10}\{\text{no duplicate}\} = 0.5031$ should really be $P_{12}\{\text{no duplicate}\} = 0.5031$. This means your answer of $k=13$ is correct.